# Automating Configuration items in xldeploy

Tags: tomcat, automation, xl-deploy

Currently, I am creating the Configuration items in xldeploy manually like adding infrastructure, environments and packages. 
Please let me know is there any process or templates to create Configuration items automatically .

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [DevOps as Code](https://docs.xebialabs.com/xl-platform/concept/get-started-with-devops-as-code.html) functionality.